# Text has zero opacity to some divs but not others

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am developing a bootstrap template that is hosted here: https://tricycle-203819.appspot.com/

There is a strange bug whereby the title `spice road` is opaque to the loresum ipsum text, but is transparent to the text in the `jumbotron` gray div. The color of the `jumbotron` gray div cannot be seen through the logo `The Spice Road`, but the text could.

I have been changing css properties in `blog.css` and `bootstrap.css` for the last 30 minutes to no avail. Has anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the header is removed from the normal flow of the content. The jumbotran is not only over the title but the header too.

Since the header is always over the other elements, you can fix it by sitting the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property of it to an arbitrary number. It is a good practice that it be more than `1000` because otherwise it may interfere with other elements' `z-index. Dosing so, the header is always over the other content of the page.

```css
.header-wrap {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

## Update

I just noticed that you have used a `background-color: rgba()`. It seems that safari does not support it. 
[image]

To fix the issue, use `rgb(255, 255, 255)` or `#FFFFFF`. You can also use bootstrap's `bg-white` class.

Comment: Ok for some reason this solution does not work safari. The header is now completely transparent to underlying divs

Comment: @chibro2 updated the answer again. I did not know that you use `rgba`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles to header-wrap nav.

```
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: ah that fixes the issue. However if I want users to click on the jumbotron, would setting z-index to -1 affect it?

Comment: That is a bad practice. The problem lies some other place

Comment: yeah you are right. deleting this answer. will get back to you if i find something

Comment: Try updated answer. Although I am nt sure why its behaving this way, but I m guessing its something to do with the header-wrap being fixed